# How to make routes private using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I want to make some routes private for admin access.
Where on successful login admin can able to access the path.
But here i am facing problem on login it is redirecting to `error page`.

Any thing else I need to do here to make this route private?
Any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

//main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Homepage from './user/Homepage';
import Aboutme from './user/AboutMe';
import Error from './user/Error';
import Dashboard from './admin/Dashboard';

class Main extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }


    render(){
        const { isAuthenticated, user } = this.props.auth;

        return(
            <Switch>
            <Route  exact path="/" component={Homepage}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={Aboutme}/>
            <Route component={Error}/>
            { user ? (user.is_admin === true && isAuthenticated ? 
           ( <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/> ) : ( <Route component={Error}/>) ):  <Route component={Error}/> }

            </Switch>

        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have

```
 <Route component={Error}/>
```

as the third item of switch.

> Switch renders the first child  or  that matches the
>   location.

Since you have no path specified, i guess it will always match, and the `Switch` won't use the later parts routes.

As a solution, either use this with a path where you redirect, or remove completely.

If you're interested in a different solution for private routes, check this article for example: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/